# How to investigate why gradle build is using cached resource ids

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

If have a gradle (5.4.1) project (plugin 3.4.1) with two flavors (`main` and `other`) using the same `sourceSets`. I've come across an issue when renaming a resource id (in a layout XML). Here are the observations:

1. Android Studio 3.4.1 doesn't show any errors and works as expected, i.e. I can click through from kotlin code to the id in the layout xml.
2. Rebuilding the `main` flavor also works as expected (no compilation errors).
3. Rebuilding the `other` flavor gives a "unresolved reference" compilation error for the new ID. Gradle `clean` does not help. However, setting `org.gradle.caching=false` in the project-level `gradle.properties` does work (following Gradle sync, Clean, Rebuild). This explains why `clean` was not helping when caching was enabled.

On closer inspection of the `R.java` file, it seems to be using IDs from some rather old project state (presumably from the gradle cache stored in the user home directory). Now, I could just delete the gradle cache, but I'd rather find out why resource ID changes are not being processed properly. Whichever way Android Studio is running builds in the background, is working fine, just not when performing Build/Run etc.

All this investigation required a lot of trial and error: switching various `gradle.properties` settings one by one to see which one was leading to the problem, and I'm still no closer to finding the root cause of the problem.

What is the best approach to solving this type of problem, or is trial and error the only way?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @MuhammadSarimMehdi sadly, no